# What folder do I place a file to pass in as a command line argument in xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4

What folder do I place a file to pass in as a command line argument in xcode 4?
I'm placing my list.txt file in the folder that xcode created but when I test for the existence of the file I'm getting NULL.I thought that when I edit the scheme and add list.txt
as an argument that the file would be passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you should pass the full path to the file, or you need to figure out the working directory that Xcode launches the executable in:

```
NSString *workingDir = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"PWD"];
NSLog(@"working directory = %@", workingDir);
```

and put your file in that dir.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put your file in a certain directory, you just need to make sure Xcode knows where you are keeping your files.

```
Product>>Edit Scheme(Command + <)
"Run ..." (from the column menu)
"Options" (tab)
```

Click the "Working Directory" check box, and browse to the directory you keep your files in.